# how to make SQL performance improvements?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle schema:

```
tableA
 AA  varchar2   PK       
 BB  number     PK                                    
 CC  varchar2   PK     
 DD  number     PK     
 EE  number
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    X1.AA,
    X1.CC,
    X1.DD,
    tableA.EE
FROM
    tableA,
    (SELECT
        AA,
        CC,
        MAX(tableA.DD) DD
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE
        (tableA.BB = 7 OR tableA.BB = 1)  AND
        tableA.EE <> 1
    GROUP BY
        AA,
        CC
    ORDER BY
        AA ASC,
        CC DESC
    ) X1,
    (SELECT
        AA,
        MAX(tableA.CC) CC
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE
        (tableA.BB = 7 OR tableA.BB = 1)  AND
        tableA.EE <> 1
    GROUP BY
        AA
    ORDER BY
        AA ASC
    ) X2
WHERE
    X2.AA = X1.AA AND
    X2.CC = X1.CC AND
    X2.AA = tableA.AA AND
    X2.CC = tableA.CC AND
    X1.DD = tableA.DD
ORDER BY
    AA ASC
```

Comment: Can't read this.  Do an EXPLAIN PLAN and look for TABLE SCAN.  If you see one, that's the reason this query is slow.

Comment: Create an Index somewhere maybe?

Comment: Remove the ORDER BY from X1 and X2 subqueries. They are futile

Comment: [edit] your question and add the execution plan for the statement and the `create index` statements for all indexes on that table. formatted text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - especially not for the execution plan.

Comment: A sample data set might also help

Comment: Please update your question to add in a sample data set along with the expected outcome of your query. This will help us understand your query by allowing us to run it and see what results you're after. Remember: we don't have access to your database or your requirements, so if you don't give us as much information as possible, the less likely we are to be able to help you. As things stand, I don't think you need all those joins, but I don't know what the query is trying to do and I've got no inclination to try and decipher it without more information from you.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @eww Can you please run performance tests of the suggested solutions on the actual data and share the results?

Answer (score 2):

This is based on YB's interpretation of the query, which is pretty much on track and probably what the OP really wants.  However, it filters the rows being output.  Instead, the filters need to be moved only for the calculations of the maximums:

```
SELECT AA, CC, DD, EE
FROM (SELECT a.*,
            MAX(CASE WHEN BB In (1, 7) AND EE <> 1 THEN CC END) OVER
                (PARTITION BY AA) As maxCC,
            MAX(CASE WHEN BB In (1, 7) AND EE <> 1 THEN DD END) OVER
                (PARTITION BY AA, CC) As maxDD
      FROM tableA a
     ) a
WHERE CC = maxCC AND DD = maxDD;
```

Comment: That's a more accurate rewrite indeed. Not sure about performance benefits using `CASE` though.

Comment: @Y.B. . . . The issue is not the performance.  I believe this matches the OP's original logic.  Your version makes more sense to me, but the logic is subtly different.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I totally agree logic-wise. You are right and thank you for pointing my error out. I have updated my answer to fix the issue. Nevertheless the question was "how to make SQL performance improvements?" and I am not sure such use of `CASE` would actually help because it will prevent the optimizer from Primary Key use. That would end up in full table scan which might be better then double sub-query join and might be not.

Comment: @Y.B. . . . The window functions should be faster than the corresponding joins.

Answer (score 1):

I understand X1 and X2 tables are used for filtering on MAX value only. In that case the query can be rewritten using windowed functions:

```
SELECT AA, CC, DD, EE
FROM (
    SELECT *
         , MAX(CC) OVER (PARTITION BY AA    ) As maxCC
         , MAX(DD) OVER (PARTITION BY AA, CC) As maxDD
    FROM tableA
    WHERE BB In (1, 7) AND EE <> 1
) A
WHERE CC = maxCC AND DD = maxDD;
```

That would save a couple of sub-query joins with own filtering each.

**Update:** With [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s comment in mind this can more accurately be rewritten as:

```
SELECT AA, CC, DD, EE
FROM tableA
WHERE (AA, CC, DD) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT AA
         , MAX(CC) OVER (PARTITION BY AA    ) As CC
         , MAX(DD) OVER (PARTITION BY AA, CC) As DD
    FROM tableA
    WHERE BB In (1, 7) AND EE <> 1
);
```

Comment: This is a good interpretation . . . and quite possibly what the OP *really* wants.  However, it is not the same as the OP's query because of that query has no filtering in the outer query.